# What happened when javascript engine interpret object literal?

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

Recently I tried to create an object using object literal. And I need a property that use another property in the object. Like this

```
var object = {
    property1:'property1',
    property2:'property2 is from ' + this.property1
};
console.log(object.property2);// property2 is from undefined
```

The `this.property1` is `undefined` in the `property2`.

I do know many ways to deal with this problem. My question is what happens behind the scenes? In other words, how javascript engine interpret object literal? I know "hoisting" happens in the function. Does "hoisting" happens in object literal?

Thanks.

Comment: `this` is function scoped, not object-initializer scoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what happens:

`this` refers to the scope where your code is running.

The same way in this code:

```
var a = 42;

var o = {
    key: a
};
```

`a` is resolved from the current scope, the `this` reference in your code is resolved to whatever `this` refers to "outside" of an object literal. (quotes with `"outside"` are used since there is no any "inside" or "outside" of literal - all the code runs in the current scope).

So technically your code could be transformed to something like

```
var a = this;

var object = {
    property1:'property1',
    property2:'property2 is from ' + a.property1
};
```

or even

```
var p = this.property1;

var object = {
    property1:'property1',
    property2:'property2 is from ' + p
};
```

so that some special properties of `this` did not confuse you.